# PHP file corrupted on download

Tags: php, wordpress

I writing code that for downloading files in image and video formats. When the form is the code is force downloaded. However, when I go to open the downloaded file, they can't be read. I am not sure if I am missing a content header type or what. I've checked on this site and my code is almost identical to many of the answers given.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['so_media'])){

        //validate file mime type
        function check_doc_mime( $tmpname ) {
            // MIME types: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php
            $tmpname = str_replace(get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads', '',$tmpname);
            $tmpname=  wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].$tmpname;
            if(!file_exists($tmpname)){
                var_dump('FILE DOES NOT EXIST');
                return FALSE;
            }
            $finfo = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
            var_dump($finfo);
            $mtype = finfo_file( $finfo, $tmpname );
            var_dump($mtype);
            finfo_close( $finfo );
            if( $mtype == ( "image/jpeg" ) ||
                $mtype == ( "image/png" ) ||
                $mtype == ( "image/gif" ) ||
                $mtype == ( "video/mp4" )
                ) {
                var_dump('Valid Mime type');
                return $mtype;
            } else {
                var_dump('Invalid Mime type');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        if($mtype = check_doc_mime($_POST['so_media'])){
            $file_name = str_replace(get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads', '', $_POST['so_media']);
            $file_name =  wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].$_POST['so_media'];
            $file_url = $file_name;
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: '.$mtype);
            header('Expires: 0');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));
            ob_clean();
        flush();
            readfile($file_url);
            exit;
        }
    }
}


//Code for the form

<form method='post' action='<?php $current_url;?>' style='display:inline-block;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='so_media' value='<?php echo $item_so_meta['upload']['url']; ?>'>
    <button class='button-white' type='submit'>Download Attached Media</button>
</form>

//end form
```

Comment: While it is legal, defining functions is confusing and prone to disaster

Comment: First error: `$file_name =  wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].$_POST['so_media'];` should probably  be `$file_name =  wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].$file_name;`

Comment: I hope you don't have the `var_dump()`'s in there when you test? If you do, they would end up being a part ot the content of the downloaded file, rendering them unusable. When returning files, you can't have any output what so ever (including spaces, new lines etc), except from the file contents.